# XML loop with jQuery - direct descendents

Tags: jquery, xml

Using the following XML, I would like to parse the data into a table with jQuery.
Unfortunately I am having some trouble getting the user degree (and not the reviewer degree too).
I haven't looked at getting firstname or lastname (I presume it will similar).

XML:

```
<data>
<status>true</status>
<candidates>
    <user>
        <username>user1</username>
        <degree>BS</degree>
        <email>test1@test.com</email>
        <firstname>John</firstname>
        <lastname>Candidate</lastname>
        <reviewedby></reviewedby>
        <notreviewedby>
            <reviewer>
                <degree>BSc</degree>
                <firstname>Eric</firstname>
                <lastname>Reviewer</lastname>
                <username>e_reviewer</username>
            </reviewer>
        </notreviewedby>
    </user>
    <user>
        <username>user2</username>
        <degree>BS</degree>
        <email>test2@test.com</email>
        <firstname>Francis</firstname>
        <lastname>CandidateAswell</lastname>
        <reviewedby></reviewedby>
            <notreviewedby>
                <reviewer>
                    <degree>BS</degree>
                    <firstname>Fred</firstname>
                    <lastname>Reviews</lastname>
                    <username>f_reviewer</username>
                </reviewer>
            </notreviewedby>
    </user>
</candidates>
```

I am not entirely sure why:

```
$(response).find('user').each(function(){
    var degree = $("> degree", this).text();
    alert(degree);
});
```

isn't working...

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: $(response).find('user').each(function(){
    var degree = $("> degree", this).text();
    alert(degree);
});
 does in fact work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `<degree>` value for each `<user>` do

```
$(response).find('user').each(function(){
    var degree = $(this).children('degree').text();
});
```

this gets all children elements of `<user>` named `degree` using [`.children([selector])`](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/pUDNc/)

Comment: thanks very much for your reply. That works fine. The example I posted as "not working" does too this morning, must have been some silly cache issue or something.

Thanks again